# Accessing protected member's public method

Tags: c++, protected

Say I have a class Permissions which has a public method change().

```
class Permissions
{
public:
  change()
}
```

I have another class File which has a protected Permissions data member and a public method getPermissions().

```
class File
{
protected:
  Permissions perm;
public:
  Permissions getPermissions() { return perm; } const;
}
```

Now File has a derived class Directory. I am trying to call the change() method from directory.cpp using getPermissions().

I have declared:

```
File *temp = new File(...);
```

I am trying to call Permissions::change() like:

```
temp->perm.change()
```

But since perm is protected I can't do that. How can I call change() using a getter like getPermissions()?

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should call change() using a getter like getPermissions():

```
temp->getPermissions().change();
```

Comment: Probably want `getPermissions()` to return a reference unless calling the function on a copy is what is desired.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. After fiddling with the code for a bit I was wondering why private data member in perm wouldn't change

Comment: So it should be Permissions &getPermissions()?